# how to add multiple baseUrl using Chopper in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible add multiple baseUrl on Chopper?

[package url](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper)

**service.dart**

```
@ChopperApi(baseUrl: 'http://55.88.209.20')
abstract class Services extends ChopperService {
  static Services create([ChopperClient client]) => _$Services(client);

  // Register User
  @Post(path: /reg-user')
  Future<Response> registerPost();
```

**chopper_client**

```
class OrelGoClient {
  final ChopperClient chopperClient;

  OrelGoClient()
      : chopperClient = ChopperClient(
            services: [Services.create()],
            baseUrl: 'http://55.88.209.20',
            interceptors: [HttpLoggingInterceptor()],
  converter:JsonConverter() ){
    Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
    Logger.root.onRecord.listen((rec) {
      print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: how you solve this?

Comment: @JohnJoe I didn't use `chopper`. I used `http`

Answer (score 1):

The recipe from [Chopper FAQ](https://hadrien-lejard.gitbook.io/chopper/faq#runtime-baseurl-change)

### Runtime baseUrl change

You may need to change the base URL of your network calls during runtime, for example, if you have to use different servers or routes dynamically in your app in case of a "regular" or a "paid" user. You can store the current server base url in your SharedPreferences (encrypt/decrypt it if needed) and use it in an interceptor like this:

```
(Request request) async =>
              SharedPreferences.containsKey('baseUrl')
                  ? request.copyWith(
                      baseUrl: SharedPreferences.getString('baseUrl'))
                  : request
```